# Node.js Request drops before Response is received

Tags: javascript, node.js

The project that I am working on is to receive a request where in the main and/or most part of that request consists of data coming from a database. Upon receiving, my system proceeds with its function which is to parse all the data and ultimately concatenates the needed information to form a query, then insert those data using the mentioned query into my local database.

It is working fine and no issue at all. Except for the fact that it takes too long to process when the request has over 6,000,000 characters and over 200,000 lines (or maybe less but still with large numbers).

I have this tested with my system being used as a server (the supposed setup in production), and with Postman as well, but both drops the connection before the final response is built and sent. I have already tested and seen that although the connection drops, my system still proceeds with processing the data even up to the query, and even until it sends its supposed response. But since the request dropped somewhere in the middle of the processing, the response is ignored.

Is this about connection timeout in nodejs?
Or limit in 'app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: '10mb'}))'?

Comment: It's most likely about connection timeout on the client side. The clients just aren't going to wait around forever for your code to respond.

Comment: @gforce301 - I have already checked this but I had doubts. But since you think the same, I'll double check it.

Comment: You increase the limit to 50mb but might not be the issue

Comment: @gforce301 - As per checking in postman, I have set the timout to 0 (which is by default), where in 0 means infinity. Still drops the connection though.

Comment: How long does it wait until it drops? A human measurable amount of time? Meaning do you see it wait a while before it drops?

Comment: @gforce301 - As per checking, 2 minutes.

Comment: @EdwinBabu - Yeah i thought the same. Already adjusted. Thanks

Comment: Ok. So I know the spec says '0' means infinity, but in reality I've **never** seen a client that waits forever. I'm surprised it waited 2 minutes. Chrome it'self seems to timeout after 1.

Comment: @gforce301 - the workaround i'm thinking is to require the client to send a request with only a certain amount of data. With huge info, the requirement is to send it by batch. However I want this to be the last resort as I'm aiming for my server to be able to take as much data as it can with a proper response, or the client to be able to wait until a response.

Answer (score 3):

I really only see 1 way around this. I have done similar in the past. Allow the client to send as much as you need/want. However, instead of trying to have the client wait around for some undetermined amount of time (at which point the client may timeout), instead send an immediate response that is basically "we got your request and we're processing it".

Now the not so great part but it's the only way I've ever solved this type of issue. In your "processing" response, send back some sort of id. Now the client can check once in a while to see if it's request has been finished by sending you that id. On the server end you store the result for the client by the id you gave them. You'll have to make a few decisions about things like how long a response id is kept around and if it can be requested more than once, things like that.

Comment: This is genius! I'll consider this.